# Heap size allocation in SUSE using MinRAMPercentage instead of MaxRAMPercentage values although heap size > 250 MB

Tags: java, heap-memory, patch, suse

I have a problem when defining usage of heap size using MinRAMPercentage and MaxRAMPercentage.

The MaxRAMPercentage value is used when heap size is > 250 MB while the MinRAMPercentage is used when heap size < 250 MB.

### I have run the following 2 commands:

**First command** is with openjdk11

docker run -m 1GB openjdk:11 java -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings -version

It allocates around **820MB** for the java heap size limit, thereby using the MaxRAMPercentage which is correct!

**Second command** is with SUSE provided openjdk

docker run -m 1GB armdocker.rnd.ericsson.se/proj-adp-cicd-drop/bob-java11mvnbuilder:latest java -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:MinRAMPercentage=50.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XshowSettings -version

It allocates **512MB** which it allocates using the MinRAMPercentage..

---

So it seems that the **First command** java uses MaxRAMPercentage, while the **second command** java uses MinRAMPercentage.
With SUSE it picks MinRAMPercentage 50%*1GB = 500 MB

Apparently there is a patch in SUSE provided jdk that switches to MinRAMPercentage although MaxRAMPercentage should be used for this heap size value (1 GB).

My questions:

- What is the reasoning behind this patch in SUSE?
- Is there a place where I can find more information
- Is there a way to avoid this patch?

Thanks.
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

As I know, SUSE has 1.3 GB as the decision limit. That is, as you have 1 GB < 1.3 GB for your container, it considers it small, and thus uses MinRAMPercentage to determine heap size. I could not find the corresponding patch yet, though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).